# Using Reflection to Bind Business Objects to ASP.NET Form Controls

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, reflection

This looks like a really useful way to simplify databinding ASP.NET controls to a generic business object. I've yet to use this in a fully fledged live project and so

I'm not sure how accurate their performance metrics are. Off the top of my head I think I would implement these two methods 'BindControlsToObject' and 'BindObjectToControls' in a new class derived from the Page object, but whatever takes your fancy really.

How I can accurate their performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If performance is one of your concerns, then do not use reflection. At least not at every page call, so you could think about caching on demand or at application start.

You could bind to a list or an object without using reflection and this would enable you to use Eval("...") in the markup, which is a commonly used pattern and other programmers new to your project would become faster productive.

Besides this, doing this is a great way to learn reflection for something like a custom plugin system ( in the cases you cannot or do not want to use MEF or Unity or something like this ).

Comment: Ok than, there is any open source that use reflection to Bind Business Objects to ASP.NET Form Controls or to Bind DAL objects to Business Objects?

Comment: For the web application I'm working on, performance is a great concern, so we do not bind using reflection but with strongly typed objects. An introduction is at MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228214.aspx